# javascript positioning an element using translate

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to position or animate an element (a div for example) to absolute x and y coordinates using translate.

I'm trying to do this with "translate" because it uses the GPU for better animation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS or jQuery to do that. Here is a plain CSS way of using `translate`:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(70px, 70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

And if you want to apply your CSS using jQuery you can use `.css()` method to set `transform` property:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = $('.element');
  var x = 70;
  var y = 70;
  el.css('transform', 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

And for animation just add `transition` property to your element:

```
.element {
  /* set transition effect only for transform property */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.container:hover .element {
  /* on hover move to position with ease 300ms transition */
  transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}
```